# Vlookup formula with variable workbook and sheet names

Tags: excel, vba

This is the part I currently have:

```
Worksheets("Data").Cells(3, CRup).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-7],'[" & TOD & "]" & flt & "'!R1C1:C18, " & CRupT & ",0)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this vba function `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`

Example :

```
Dim lk_Val = 'Lookup Value String'

    Worksheet("DestinationSheet").Range("A1") = WorkApplication.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lk_Val,Workbooks("YourSourceWorkbook").Sheets("YourSourceSheet").Range("A:B"),2,False)
```

### As far as i know the workbook must be opened

Comment: Hi Folk's, Above code is not working plz check " Worksheets("Data").Cells(3, CRup) = WorkApplication.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(B3, Workbooks(" & TOD & ").Sheets("& flt &").Range("A:AE"), " & CRupT & ", False)"